# Allow other sites to embed videos though iframe options is set to Sameorigin in the response header

Tags: video, embed, same-origin-policy, x-frame-options

We have a videos website much like Youtube. Our site allows other users to view videos and also embed our videos in their sites using the `<iframe>`, again much like youtube.
The site owner has asked to change the x-frame options response header to "SameOrigin" which was earlier set as "*". Now our website is not *embedable*
The site owner/customer has asked a workaround for it. We have been searching for a solution but in vain.
Please suggest a solution/workaround for the above problem. Also if it is not technically possible to achieve it then what should be a layman answer to it.
Thank you for reading. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can I allow x-frame options only for a particular page of my website. What I mean is that only the video page's url can be opened as an iframe on other websites and not the other pages.Is this a possible workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Can I allow x-frame only for a particular page ?
yes, you can.create a subdomain for embeding url.